# Running the tar command with the --exclude functionality does not work for directories

Tags: tar

I use

```
tar hczf t.tar.gz * --exclude="./test1"
```

where test1 is the name of a directory that I want to prevent from being tarred.

Unfortunately, tar still includes the directory test1. How can I have tar exclude directories?

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that to prevent the tarring of a directory you need to change where you're adding the --exclude

```
tar --exclude="./test1" -hczf t.tar.gz *
```

works

Answer (score 1):

The arguments come before the files.

```
tar hczf t.tar.gz --exclude="test1" *
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
tar hczf t.tar.gz * --exclude="test1"
```

Comment: tried that didn't work

Comment: I get the error tar: --exclude=test1: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Comment: edited to include the 1 in test1

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: then test1 doesn't exist in the current working directory

Comment: it does exist in the directory